# Insert date into database winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to insert a row in my table with a bunch of data, including a date (using the Date type field)

The input is received from a usercontrol and then put into parameters:

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("titel", titel);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dvu" , dvu );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("genre", genreID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("paginas", paginas);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("taal", taalID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("isbn13", isbn13);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("isbn10", isbn10);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uitgever", uitgever);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("auteur", auteurID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bindwijze", bindwijzeID);
```

As shown above, the 'dvu' is the date to be added. It's format entered is DD-MM-YYYY. However, when I execute the query as follows:

```
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Boek (ItemID, AuteurID, BoekGenreID,
        BindwijzeID, TaalID, ISBN10, ISBN13, AantalPagina) 
        VALUES (@itemID, @auteur, @genre, @bindwijze, 
        @taal, @isbn10, @isbn13, @paginas);";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

The date does not get inserted into the database, where as the other data does get inserted.

How can I fix this?

Edit: Fixed. I totally forgot to include them in my query! :/ Sorry!

Comment: Since you mention a format, it looks like you are binding the `dvu` parameter to a `string` variable. I suggest you use a `DateTime` variable. But first, make sure the `dvu` column is included in your SQL. It looks like you forgot about it.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the dvu parameter and field name to the query

Comment: Geez, thank you, Steve, I forgot to add it =.=

Comment: Just take a look at your original query ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't contain the field name and the parameter. Of course nothing is inserted in the table for the field (suppose it is called DVU)

```
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Boek (ItemID, DVU, AuteurID, BoekGenreID,
    BindwijzeID, TaalID, ISBN10, ISBN13, AantalPagina) 
    VALUES (@itemID, @dvu, @auteur, @genre, @bindwijze, 
    @taal, @isbn10, @isbn13, @paginas);";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```